# How to change opacity of disabled inputText element in Primefaces?

Tags: css, primefaces

I added this class to my .css:

```
.ui-state-disabled .boldText {
    font-weight: bold !important;
    opacity: .65 !important;
}
```

And I added this class to my inputText:

```
<p:inputText id="myInput" styleClass="boldText" value="#{myController.myValue}" />
```

Sadly this isn't doing anything only if I remove the .ui-state-disabled class. But I want to use this to change only the disabled behavior...

What am I missing here? Thank you.

Comment: _"What am I missing here?"_ The right selector. Aee the partial overriding in the duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)

Comment: Okay and what is the right selector?

Comment: It is in duplicate, the piece I referred to. Find the difference with your selector. Use a browser developer tool and see where the style class is actually applied and learn from basic css how to apply a selector where both classes are in the same class attribute. Oh shoot now I gave away another hint